# ASP.NET MVC Identity 2.0 Very frequent unexpected user logoff

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 Application with ASPNet.Identity 2.0 security system.
So, I have frequent situation when user first logs in the site and some clicks later (from 1 to 20) he suddenly logs off.
This occurs only on live system (on hosting with IIS 8.5).

The asp.net cookie does not change its value.

And there is no such error on development with IIS Express.

How can that happen?
Maybe it's about some IIS settings?

It's the only one application on domain and in app.pool.

Comment: Do you have any cookies set? Session does not change?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my trouble, with generating machine key in my Web.Config.